# ¿Los lenguajes de programación diferencian operadores de identificadores y por eso pueden estar sin un espacio que los separe?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico, sintaxis

Por ejemplo, si tengo:

```
let variable=9
```

No pasa nada (no da error) por lo mismo que dije en el encabezado de la pregunta, ¿es correcto verlo de esa forma?

¿Cuando se necesitan espacios es cuando hay que diferenciar la estructura de una instrucción que lleva palabras reservadas y identificadores?

¿Por ejemplo aquí no se necesitarían espacios entre `function` y `()` porque el lenguaje diferencia operadores de identificadores y palabras reservadas?

```
const mi_funcion = function(){
   console.log(1+2)
}
```

Si hubiese un nombre de función por razones obvias se necesitaría diferenciar la declaración function y su nombre no porque no se sabría si se esta declarando una función si se unifica todo como una frase?

- ¿Puedo aplicar este principio a todos los lenguajes e incluso llevarlos a aquellos que no sean de programación como CSS y HTML?
- ¿los lenguajes diferencian las diferentes estructuras excepto aquellas que puedan causar conflictos como el unir una palabra reservada con un identificador ya que no se entendería la instrucción porque se tendría una sola palabra mientras que aquellas que son diferentes totalmente en cuanto a sintaxis no tendrían ningún problema en ser interpretadas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los lenguajes de programación tienen una semántica, y la misma es interpretada por los compiladores.

Mientras mejor sea el compilador, mas facilidades para escribir en el mismo vas a tener. Esto no tiene nada que ver con dejar o no dejar espacios entre las cosas. Ten en cuenta, que se denomina Token a cada parte de la semántica de un lenguaje.

Ahora, vos estas hablando de identificar cada token del lenguaje. Y eso, justamente, lo hace el compilador.

Las palabras reservadas, se identifican porque estan rodeadas de espacios o algun carácter que empieze un nuevo token. En general, en la definición de cada lenguaje, se especifica exactamente cada token a usar.

Tus funciones por ejemplo, pasarían a ser un nuevo token, pero de tu programa, igual que tus variables y otras cosas que puedas llegar a usar en el mismo.

Cuando un compilador va desarmando tu código para construir el código compilado (o para interpretar el mismo) va desarmando casi (digo casi, porque no todos los compiladores hacen lo mismo) carácter a carácter, y generando un árbol de ejecución con los tokens que va encontrando.

Por eso, por ejemplo, tu compilador no confunde la palabra reservada `if` con tu función mom**if**icar. sabe que la palabra reservada if, empieza en donde termina un token terminador (y seguro la letra m no lo es, pero un espacio si lo seria, o un ;, o una linea nueva) y termina con otro token terminador (un espacio, un paréntesis de apertura, una nueva linea).

Comment: ¿Tendría que estudiar los tokens terminadores del lenguaje en concreto para saber enfrentarme a situaciones en donde tenga que decidr si es posible que este pegado a otro token un identificador o no por ejemplo?

¿Que me recomiendas hacer para superar esta dificultad que tengo en diferenciar estas cosas?, yo tengo un tiempo programando y nunca me había hecho una pregunta como la que hice

Comment: @EngelSandoval cuando estudias un lenguaje, tal vez inconcientemente, al saber como funciona el mismo, lo estas estudiando...

Answer (score 2):

Depende totalmente del lenguaje, no se puede generalizar para todos, como comentó @gbianchi los lenguajes tienen una sintaxis y una semántica que es usada por los compiladores o interpretes.

Algunas versiones de fortran ignoran totalmente los espacios.

Para otros lenguajes, como Python, los espacios son tan importantes que se usan para limitar bloques de código (lo que hacen `{}` en otros como C o Java).

En el libro [Programming C#](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-c/0596001177/ch03s04.html) puedes encontrar que C# tiene reglas especiales como estas:

> En el lenguaje C#, los espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea se consideran  " espacio blanco”. El espacio blanco generalmente se ignora en las sentencias de C#. Entonces puedes escribir:
>
> `myVariable = 5;`
>
> o:
>
> `myVariable    =                             5;`
>
> Y el compilador las tratará como idénticas
>
> La excepción a esta regla es que el espacio dentro de cadenas no es ignorado. Si escribes:
>
> `Console.WriteLine("Hola Mundo");`
>
> El espacio entre  `“Hola”` y `“Mundo”` es tratado como cualquier otro caracter de la cadena.
>
> La mayor parte del tiempo el uso de espacios en blanco es intuitivo. El punto clave es usar el espacio en blanco para hacer el código más legible a otros programadores; para el compilador es indiferente.
>
> Sin embargo, hay excepciones donde el espacio en blanco es significativo, aunque la expresion:
>
> `int x = 5;`
>
> es la misma que:
>
> `int x=5;`
>
> esta no es lo mismo que:
>
> `intx=5;`
>
> El compilador sabe que un espacio en blanco es indiferente en cualquier lado de la asignación, pero el espacio blanco entre la declaración de tipo y el nombre de la variable x no es un extra y es requerido. Esto no es sorpresa; el espacio en blanco ayuda al compilador a traducir la palabra clave `int` en lugar un termino desconocido como `intx`. Eres libre de agregar mucho o poco espacio entre `int` y `x` siempre y cuando haya al menos un espacio en blanco (espacio o tabulador).

Mi recomendación personal es que no te preocupes por darle formato a tu código de forma manual y al final ocupes un mecanismo automático para darle formato a los espacios en blanco. Por ejemplo en visual estudio puedes usar <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]